# What is the difference between up and upon?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, difference, grammaticality

Sometimes the preposition *‘upon‘* can be used to indicate *‘movement from a lower level to a higher level, keeping in touch with the surface‘* :

> *‘We went upon the hill.‘*

But in this case, we can use the preposition *‘up‘* also :

> *‘We went up the hill.‘*

What is the difference between *‘up‘* and *‘upon‘* in the above sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find *We went upon the hill* particularly idiomatic. *Upon* usually describes a position rather than movement. It's far more natural to say

> We went up the hill

but you can say

> We stood upon the summit of the hill, admiring the view.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder where you found that definition. It's misleading, I think.

As [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/upon) says,

> The preposition **upon** has the same core meaning as the preposition **on**. However, in modern English **upon** tends to be restricted to more formal contexts
> or to established phrases and idioms, as in "once upon a time" and "row
> upon row of seats"

There are a great many established phrases and idioms, but we wouldn't normally 'go upon a hill'.

You might find the Macmillan ([British](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/upon) or [American](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/upon)) dictionary helpful.